# How to create a module at runtime in AngularJS?

Tags: javascript, angularjs, firefox, angularjs-module

I want to be able to create AngularJS modules at runtime, so I do this:

```
<section class="panel portlet-item" id="crashpanel"></section>
<script type="text/javascript">
var angularApp = angular.module("Crashpanel", []);
angularApp.controller("CrashpanelCtrl", function ($scope, $http, $compile)
{
    console.log("Hello");
});
angular.bootstrap(angular.element("#crashpanel"), [ "Crashpanel" ]);
</script>
```

But "Hello" is not displayed, because the controller is not attached to the element. How to be able to attach the controller to the element ?

Comment: you want to attach your controller to your section at runtime? Do you really need this?

Comment: @Rodrigo Yes, else I get the following error : http://docs.angularjs.org/error/ng:areq?p0=CrashpanelCtrl&p1=not%20a%20function,%20got%20undefined

Comment: put ng-app="Crashpanel"

Comment: @Rodrigo Still get the error, though everything I do afterwards works on Google chrome but still doesn't work on Firefox and that's the bug I'm trying to resolve.

Comment: do you really need to use this: angular.bootstrap(angular.element("#crashpanel"), [ "Crashpanel" ]);??

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to put the *data-ng-app="Crashpanel"* somewhere in your code to make a reference to your module if you want, example:

```
<html data-ng-app="Crashpanel">
```

Your section must have a *ng-controller* attribute(like the another user said) to make a reference to your controller.

```
<section class="panel portlet-item" id="crashpanel" data-ng-controller="CrashpanelCtrl"></section>
```

Comment: Thanks! It works, but I don't understand why... What is the difference between having the ng-app on the html tag and having it on the section tag ?

Comment: this directive auto-bootstrap your application, i think(i don't have sure) that after angularjs in compile phase find this directive, it will only look for any other directives below(children) of this html element, not the element itself.

Answer (score 0):

Change your element to this:

```
<section class="panel portlet-item" id="crashpanel" data-ng-controller="CrashpanelCtrl"></section>
```

Comment: I get this error http://docs.angularjs.org/error/ng:areq?p0=CrashpanelCtrl&p1=not%20a%20function,%20got%20undefined